# No se en que parte del codigo tengo que cambiar para que imprima lo que me piden

Tags: python

Una cadena de ADN es una secuencia de bases nitrogenadas llamadas: (1) adenina, (2) citosina, (3) timina y (4) guanina. En un programa una cadena se representa como un string de caracteres ‘a’, ‘c’, ‘t’ y ‘g’. Escriba la función cadena_al_azar(n) que retorne una cadena aleatoria de ADN a partir de largo n que debe ser ingresado por el usuario.

```
   >>> cadena_al_azar(10)
    ‘acgtccgcct’
    (ESTO ES LO QUE ME PIDEN)
from random import choice

def cadena_al_azar(n):
    cad=""
    for i in range(n):
        cad=cad+choice("actg")
        return cad
def cadena2(n):
    i=0
    cad=""
    while i<n:
        cad+=choice("actg")
        i+=1
        return cad
largo=int(input(f"Ingrese el largo de la cadena"))
adn=cadena_al_azar(largo)
print(adn)
```

(ESTO ES LO QUE HICE)

Comment: La indentación es importante en Python.

Answer (score 0):

Estás muy cerca de tener el código funcionando. Lo que ocurre es que el `return` en la función `cadena_al_azar()` está dentro del ciclo for, y debe estar fuera:

```
def cadena_al_azar(n):
    cad=""
    for i in range(n):
        cad=cad+choice("actg")
    return cad
```

Saludos.